# Code conflict between packages \systeme, \amsmath, \enumerate & \tasks

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, enumitem, tasks

Stackers:

I stitched together 3 difference code sections from various stack users in a attempt to create:

1. a 2 col. horizontally enumerated math problem set for a system of linear equations.
2. the system of 2 equations uses \systeme (h/t @egreg) for alignment.
3. directly beneath the system of equations I want to display step-by-step solution procedure in a "stacked" vertical alignment wherein the variable is isolated.

Unfortunately, the present code only renders the first line of text.

This utterly latex-befuddled newbie requests your assistance.

Thanks in advance!

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{multicol}
%the enumeration is horizontal with only the system of equations with cleft curly brace enumerated
% 1) {x +   y = 3
%     2x + 3y = 6
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}
\settasks{after-item-skip=5em,
          after-skip=2cm,
          label-width=2em,
          item-indent=3em,
          label=(\arabic*),
          column-sep=2em
 }         
\begin{document}

Solve each system of equations using the \textbf {elimination method}:

\begin{tasks}(2)
\[
\syslineskipcoeff{1}
\systeme*{-7x+7y=14, -3x-y=26}
\]
%step-by-step solution procedure goes here. 
Solution procedure uses vertical stack. (h/t @mico)
%Numbers below are only example layout and don't match the original system of equations.
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{RCRCRCR}
 3x & - & 2y & = & \multicolumn{3}{R}{-1} \\
-3x &   &    &   & -3x \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{R}{-2y} & = & -3x & - &  1 \\[2.5ex]
\multicolumn{3}{R}{\frac{-2y}{-2}} & = & 
     \multicolumn{3}{R}{\frac{-3x-1}{-2}}\\[3ex]
& & y & = & \frac{3x}{2} & + & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{tasks}
end{enumitem,tasks}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `\task` command and $...$, not `\[...\]`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{systeme}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem,tasks}

\settasks{
%  after-item-skip=5em,
%  after-skip=2cm,
  label-width=2em,
  item-indent=3em,
  label=(\arabic*),
  column-sep=2em,
 }
\begin{document}

Solve each system of equations using the \textbf {elimination method}:

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\syslineskipcoeff{1}\systeme*{-7x+7y=14, -3x-y=26}$
\\
$\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
 3x & - & 2y & = & \multicolumn{3}{r}{-1} \\
-3x &   &    &   & -3x \\
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{r}{-2y} & = & -3x & - &  1 \\[2.5ex]
\multicolumn{3}{r}{\frac{-2y}{-2}} & = & 
     \multicolumn{3}{r}{\frac{-3x-1}{-2}}\\[3ex]
& & y & = & \frac{3x}{2} & + & \frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}$
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: I replaced `R` and `C` with `r` and `c` as you don't show how these column types are defined.

Comment: thanks so much for providing an easy-to-understand and beautiful solution for my worksheet!

Comment: thank you for your always generous fixes to my MacGyvered code. Your explanations are also most appreciated!